# Ubuntu One stuck on "Getting information, please wait..." , Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu-one-windows

I know, this has been asked before ( https://askubuntu.com/questions/124345/win-7-ultimate-wont-run-ubuntu-one-getting-information-please-wait-forev ), and I have already tried out the suggested answer, but it didn't work for me.

The situation is really that simple:
I start Ubuntu One, latest version (afaik, it just updated itself). The main screen is grayed out. A message is displayed "Getting information, please wait..." with a loading bar going back and forth all the time.

I have waited for more than an hour now. I have tried restarting it as administrator after killing all related process, but the situation remains the same.

I'm using Windows 7, latest updates. Any more information required?

Any suggestions?

Comment: As far as I know this was a bug with previous version, but now it's solved. You can give a try to uninstall U1 and reinstall U1 again.

Comment: The service is obsolete

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem for a few months, as bad as I have decided to just drop the software. 
A few months later, I found the win xp version has already been developed to 4.20 version, installed it numerous times, tried to completely remove and nothing seemed to work until I have deleted xdg folder under application data.
It definitely worth a shot. I am on xp sp3 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

I had what seems to be the same problem under Win XP. All the linux clients worked perfectly with U1, but then I started to get the "Getting information, please wait" message under XP. Perhaps an update had happened secretly...or a long time ago and I had not started the client gui and so I had not seen the message. I think that the last client I installed was 3.0.2b.

I tried uninstalling and re-installing and it did not fix the situation. I deleted the ubuntuone and xdg directories under Local Settings\Application Data and then reinstalled 4.2. It started to work fine.